# constructing sigma-field generated by certain set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, statistics

i'm studying mathematical statistics.

and i got a problem that finding a $\sigma$-field generated by $D$ = {A,B}

the answer i heard(from professor..) is

$B$ = {$\varnothing$ , A, B, A$^c$,B$^c$, A$\cup$B , A$\cap$B, A$^c$$\cap$B$^c$}

that's it. but when i think about the countable union of element in $B$ is contained in $B$.

there might be more element in $B$. like A$^c$$\cup$B$^c$ this one.

is there anybody who can explain about this one?

---

why complement of A$\cap$B is not in the $B$ ? to be a $\sigma$-field , as i know that the compelement of element should be contained in $\sigma$-field.
then is $B$ above wrong?

Comment: The answe you heard is incorrect. The $\sigma$-field generated by $D = \{A,B\} $ in a space $X$ has 16 elements and it is: 

$$\Sigma = \{\emptyset  , A, B, A\cap B , A\cup B,  A^c, A \cup A^c, B \cap A^c , B \cup A^c, B^c, A\cap B^c, A\cup B^c, A^c \cap B^c, A^c\cup B^c, (A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c), (A\cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) \}$$

Note that $A \cup A^c$ is the whole space $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you heard is incorrect. The σ-field generated by $D=\{A,B\}$ in a space $X$ has 16 elements and it is, in the general case :
$$\Sigma=\{\emptyset,A,B,A\cap B,A\cup B,A^c,A\cup A^c,B\cap A^c,B\cup A^c,B^c,A\cap Bc,A\cup B^c,A^c\cap B^c, \\ A^c\cup B^c,(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c),(A\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B^c)\}$$
Note that $A\cup A^c$ is the whole space $X$.

Of course, for some specific example of $A$ and $B$, $\Sigma$ may be smaller. For instance if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets and $A\cup B =X$, then $\Sigma$ reduces to only four elements, namely,  $\Sigma=\{\emptyset, A, B, A\cup B\}$.